# Complex algorithm: how to reconstruct OR rules from data

Tags: algorithm, boolean, time-complexity

I have a boolean table with ~100000 rows and 3000 columns. I know that many of these columns are redundant because they are the result of OR between some other columns in the table (even maybe up to 200 other columns). The structure is also nested - some columns may be constructed from ORing other columns and then themselves be involved in creating a new column.

My goal is to reduce this table into "base columns" and a list of OR rules which allow me to reconstruct the original data.

Is there any way to do this in a reasonable amount of run-time?

Comment: Maybe some kind of PCA

Comment: Reconstructing the OR operations that created the data is impossible. If you have one row and three columns: true, false, true. Column 1 may have been the result of or-ing column 2 and 3. Column 3 may have been the result of or-ing 1 and 2 or all columns may have been untouched input to which no or-operations were applied. Given this are you perhaps looking for the representation of the data as or-operations over columns that uses the minimum number of input columns?

Comment: I believe in some cases at least it is possible.. if I have more rows than columns, and I can find that only one column is the or of the rest as it is the fullest of True values, non-other could have been constructed by it.
However, technically I don't care who created the data and which OR rules they used, I just want to simplify the data to be more memory efficient, so even if i reconstruct the wrong rule, as long as it works that's fine.